# SQL Server - INSERT failed because of 'ARITHABORT'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, calculated-columns, database-indexes

I use NHibernate and SQL Server 2005 and I have an index on a computed column in one of my tables.

My problem is that when I insert a record to that table I get the following error:

> *INSERT failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'ARITHABORT'*

I use `SET ARITHABORT ON;` before my inserts but still have this error.

Answer (score 9):

For inserts on tables with computed columns, you need these set options:

The NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT option must be set to OFF, and the following options must be set to ON:

```
ANSI_NULLS
ANSI_PADDING
ANSI_WARNINGS
ARITHABORT
CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL
QUOTED_IDENTIFIER
```

Try adding this before your insert:

```
set NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT off
set ANSI_NULLS, ANSI_PADDING, ANSI_WARNINGS, ARITHABORT, CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER on

insert ...
```

Comment: what do you mean by `on your connection`? should I set these on session creation in NHibernate? I only set `ARITHABORT` to `ON` on insert, update and delete.

Comment: These are session level options, so only need to be done once on the connection, but you can set them multiple times without causing a problem. See updated answer

Comment: I use Fluent NHibernate. Can you show me how to configure it?

Comment: I tried your solution but it still does not work. I have read that indexes on computed columns should be created with `ARITHABORT` on. should it be set `ON` on creation? How should I do that?

Comment: Do you get the same error? It must be some kind of interaction with NHibernate. When you create the index, i.e. run the sql "create index ...", run those two set lines from above first.

Comment: Yes. the same error. Even I dropped the index and still got the same error. I do not have such an error on the development machine but I get it on the main server.

Comment: I had a similar problem. My solution was to drop the index on the computed columns, execute the insert/delete, then rebuild each index. Unfortunately I can't understand why this hasn't worked for you @S.M.Amin  Did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 8):

I ran into this problem today and got it solved.

I created a filtered index on a column in **sql server 2008 r2**, but would get this error when inserting.

I saw that this question wasn't completely answered since it might be tedious to always `SET ARITHABORT ON` in every insert.

I found a blog that showed it was the database compatibility level that was the issue. I changed the compatibility level from **80** (2000) to **100** (2008) and the issue was solved. Not sure if changing the compatibility level to 90 would solve this or not, but worth a try.

SQL Server compatibility levels and command to change here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx

If this doesn't work or you can't change the compatibility mode, there is another workaround by adding a trigger in the blog I was talking about here http://chrismay.org/2013/05/23/interesting-problem-with-sql-server-arithabort-filtered-indexes-calculated-columns-and-compatibility-mode-of-80/

Note that this change was done on a test database, and all applications should be tested before making a change like this in production. Make sure this is ok with your DBA before changing too.

Comment: I sincerely hope your resident DBA authorized the change in *compatibilitylevel*. Making this change is not to be done lightly, or without extensive testing of all applications sing the database.

Comment: I am the DBA and it was on a test database that is scripted to weekly restore from production to make sure the back ups are good :-) Have to do more testing before it can be changed in production.

Comment: Good. That should be added to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Open SQL Server Mgt Studio, right click on the server name, choose Properties, open Connection Tab and then check the arithmetic abort option

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this error while executing a stored procedure (that updates records) from an application and this solved my problem: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/305333

So basically, I added this set of codes before executing my stored procedure

```
sqlConn = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
If sqlConn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then sqlConn.Open()

sqlCmd = New SqlCommand()
With sqlCmd
   .Connection = sqlConn
   .CommandType = CommandType.text
   .CommandText = "SET ARITHABORT ON"
   .ExecuteNonQuery()

   .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
   .CommandText = "MY PROCEDURE"
   .ExecuteNonQuery()
End With
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the database options, so the SET options are globally available

```
    ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
        SET ANSI_NULLS OFF,
            ANSI_PADDING OFF,
            ANSI_WARNINGS OFF,
            ARITHABORT OFF,
            CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF,
            NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF,
            QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
        WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
```