# UPDATE failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'ARITHABORT'

Tags: c#, sql-server

> UPDATE failed because the following SET options have incorrect
>   settings: 'ARITHABORT'. Verify that SET options are correct for use
>   with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered
>   indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or
>   spatial index operations.

even after setting the OPTION in the code.

```
sqlCommand.CommandText = "SET ARITHABORT ON";
 sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConn;
 sqlConn.Open();
 sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

 sqlCommand.CommandText = @"UPDATE Customer SET status = 1";
sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
sqlConn.Close();
```

*WHAT DIDN'T WORK*

Setting the option in the code right before Update stmt or as a separate SqlCommand using the same connection.

Dropping the trigger on the table update.

Setting options while creating the indexed view.

Setting the options while creating the indexes.

*WHAT WORKED*

One of the answers from here finally worked
[SQL Server - INSERT failed because of 'ARITHABORT'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953450/sql-server-insert-failed-because-of-arithabort?rq=1)

Open SQL Server Mgt Studio, right click on the server name, choose Properties, open Connection Tab and then check the arithmetic abort option

Comment: Many issues could lead to this error being shown (e.g. closing/reopening connection or using a different connection for the next query) but you've not shown us enough code for us to diagnose it.

Comment: use `sqlCommand.CommandText = @"SET ARITHABORT ON; UPDATE Customer SET"`

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever both execute stmts are in the same using clauses for connection and  sqlcommand. sqlconn is closed after the execute of update.

Comment: @MartinSmith , according to MSDN, the option should be set in a different batch. but I have already tried what you suggested.

Comment: Is this exactly the SQL code your c# is sending?  And it's not executing a stored procedure with the UPDATE in it?  Otherwise, I'd start checking for triggers.

Comment: @RBarryYoun This is the SQL but there is an Update trigger on the table so we added SET ARITHABORT ON in the trigger after BEGIN. But I also turned off/dropped the trigger and tried updating with no luck.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

WHAT DIDN'T WORK

Setting the option in the code right before Update stmt or as a separate SqlCommand using the same connection.

Dropping the trigger on the table update.

Setting options while creating the indexed view.

Setting the options while creating the indexes.

WHAT WORKED

One of the answers from here finally worked SQL Server - INSERT failed because of 'ARITHABORT'

Open SQL Server Mgt Studio, right click on the server name, choose Properties, open Connection Tab and then check the arithmetic abort option